# Iterate two dimensional (2n+1)*(2n+1) array from center out

Tags: arrays, iteration

I have to sort some values from a square two dimesional array with odd dimensions.
I'm interested in how I would iterate in such a way that it would go from center out in a kind of a spiral square motion

It's hard to explain with words, so I will explain graphically
numbers represent the state of iteration from 0 to arraylength*arraylength-1 ( numbers from 10 onwards are alphabet characters, since I ran out of digits) ( so a = 10, b = 11, c = 12...)

Like this:

```
fghij
e456k
d307l
c218m
ba9on
```

As you can see, it goes from center out in a circural motion. and when it fills a circle, it begins from outer layer outwards ( step from 1 to 2. or the step from 8 to 9 for instance)

I assume it would make sense to start like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length()/2; i++)
    for (int j = 0; i < i*8 || i == 0 && j == 0; j++)
        ....
```

Since j represents the number of fields in the i level you're gonna iterate around which is: i*8
in the second layer there's 1*8=8 fields to go around, in third 2*8 = 16 on in fourth 3*8 = 24 etc.. except for the center one where there's only one

Feel free to answer in any programming language ;)... except Fortran. in which case you should rethink your life

Comment: There is a common rule that dictates when you should go from left to up, from up to right, from right to down and from down to left.  Once you have identified those rules, coding it should be trivial...

Comment: You need to identify the rules first; how would you do this with pen and paper?  Until you've figured that out, it's not a programming question.

Comment: thank you, I'd be lost without you